# Calculus for the Practical Man: Chapter 17, Problem 6

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

A small mass sliding on a certain inclined plane is subject to an
acceleration downward along the plane of $4$ feet per second. If it
started upward from the bottom of the incline with a velocity of $6$ feet per
second, then find the distance it moves in $t$ seconds. How far will it go before stopping
and starting to slide back?

Comment: In a way, this post seems perfectly reasonable. I believe this is how many "practical men" would solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In a way, this post seems perfectly reasonable. I believe this is how many "practical men" would solve this problem."  John Douma

Am I missing something?  This appears to be a response to a solution but I see no solution!

In addition, this problem states that the acceleration is "4 feet per second" but "feet per second" is NOT a measure of acceleration!

If -4 feet per second per second was meant (negative since it is back toward the ground) then, with a starting speed of 6 feet per second, then, after t seconds this object will have speed 6- 4t feet per second and will have gone 6t- 2t^2 feet.

The object will stop and turn back when its speed is 0 so when 6- 4t= 0.  4t= 6 so t= 6/4= 3/2 second.  At that time it will have gone up the slope 6(3/2)- 2(9/4)= 18/2- 9/2= 9/2 or 4.5 feet.